# How do you make the Pi 4 think it is plugged to HDMI even if its not?

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, remote

So my project needs to use Team-viewer or Any-desk to remote control the PI 4 after boot.

The problem I'm facing is, if the PI is connected to a screen everything works perfectly and the 2 programs run automatically, but the project should not have a screen connected to it, and then it will face a problem to not open these programs on boot up.

I already set the programs to start at boot but not sure why it is not working if no screen is connected.

Is there is a way to make the PI think that there a screen plugged in when booting?

**Edit**: I did enable this option

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

also I added

```
# DVI DMT (35) RGB full 5:4, 1280x1024 @ 60.00Hz 
hdmi_group=2 
hdmi_mode=35
```

and I set the resolutions in `raspi-config`.

When I connect to the Pi using remote desktop from the same network it works, but the thing that still does not starting at boot is TeamViewer and anydesk. The moment I connect a screen and reboot everything will work, but if I remove it and reboot, Teamviewer and Anydesk do not start anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in `config.txt`, although AFAIK the Pi4 will always use HDMI unless overridden, but it will do no harm.

You should also set a resolution in `raspi-config` otherwise the Pi will use an impossibly small screen.

On my Pi4 this sets

```
#DVI DMT (35) RGB full 5:4, 1280x1024 @ 60.00Hz
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=35
```

and this can be set manually in `config.txt`

The Pi4 has an additional GUI **Screen Configuration** utility which allows the screen to be configured after boot.

Comment: sorry, I did able this option hdmi_force_hotplug=1

 also I add
#DVI DMT (35) RGB full 5:4, 1280x1024 @ 60.00Hz
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=35

and I set the resolutions here  raspi-config

as open using remote desktop from the same network I still  can open and the thing that still not starting by boot is TeamViewer and anydesk , the moment I plug the screen and reboot everything will work and if I take it and reboot nothing working (teamviewer and anydesk)

Comment: I'm really sorry, as I'm new on all of this  and I'm windows user I cant get it what other info I should get for you, but I can give you access to my Pi to have a Look if that possible I will be grateful ,this my email ghazpi4@gmail.com .Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

It's been a year since the last reply, but just to add -- there's also a hardware way of doing this. There are small devices which plug into a HDMI-port and emulate a monitor.

If you use such a device on a Pi, the Pi will think there's an actual monitor connected.

The ones I've seen are normal sized HDMI connectors, but I'm sure there will be micro-HDMI ones too or otherwise there are adapters from normal HDMI to micro.

Comment: Are you talking about "HDMI grabber/capture" devices ?